# Stacked bar offset in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is a code for stacked bar using matplotlib (C0 and C2 are predefined arrays)

```
N = 1
width = 0.1
ind = [i+1 for i in range(N)]

colorsArr = plt.cm.BuPu(np.linspace(0, 0.5, len(C2)))
p = numpy.empty(len(C2), dtype=object)
plt.figure(figsize=(11,11))

prevBar = 0
for index in range(len(C2)):
    plt.bar(ind, C2[index], width, bottom=prevBar, color=colorsArr[index], label=C0[index])
    prevBar = prevBar + C2[index]

# positions of the x-axis ticks (center of the bars as bar labels)
tick_pos = [i+(width/2) for i in ind]

plt.ylabel('Home Category')
plt.title('Affinity - Retail Details(Home category)')
# set the x ticks with names
plt.xticks(tick_pos, ['All Transactions'])
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,70000,3000))
plt.legend(title="Line" )
plt.show()
```

As a result I get the following plot. I want the plot be more narrow and start from offset - How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Leaving aside the issue of whether this is really the best way to visualize your data, you can do what you want by passing `ind = [0]*N` as your x-axis, centering the single bar with `align='center'` and then using `plt.xlim(-width*2, width*2)` to pad either side of the bar's width by as much as you want (adjust the factor of 2):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 1

C2 = [1400, 5000, 5400, 6000, 12000]
C0 = ['label%d' % (e+1) for e in range(len(C2))]
width = 0.1
ind = [0]*N

colorsArr = plt.cm.BuPu(np.linspace(0, 0.5, len(C2)))
p = np.empty(len(C2), dtype=object)
plt.figure(figsize=(11,11))

prevBar = 0
for index in range(len(C2)):
    plt.bar(ind, C2[index], width, bottom=prevBar, color=colorsArr[index], label=C0[index], align='center')
    prevBar = prevBar + C2[index]

# positions of the x-axis ticks (center of the bars as bar labels)
tick_pos = [0]

plt.ylabel('Home Category')
plt.title('Affinity - Retail Details(Home category)')
# set the x ticks with names
plt.xticks(tick_pos, ['All Transactions'])
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,70000,3000))
plt.legend(title="Line" )
plt.xlim(-width*2, width*2)
plt.show()
```

[image]